# Getting Property Values Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Reflection to get values on basis of specified dynamic column name(model property).

My issue is when i pass propName, it is in All Caps, if i convert it in `LowerCase()`, still it doesn't match with the `Model property`.

Here is Code :-

```
public object GetPropValue(object obj, string propName)
{
     return obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(obj, null);
}


 var Fields = obj.GetPropValue(Employee, item.Key);  // item.key = 'ADDRESS'

public class Employee
{
      public string Address { get; set; }
      ....
}
```

What is solution for this?

Comment: How `item` is defined?

Comment: it comes from foreach....Value comes from database table...which is in All Caps.

Comment: So, you suppose, that we must guess, what type `item` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the exact property name case:

```
public object GetPropValue(object obj, string propName)
{
    var property = obj.GetType()
                      .GetProperties()
                      .SingleOrDefault(p=>p.Name.Equals(propName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

    return property != null ? property.GetValue(obj, null) : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass [`BindingFlags.IgnoreCase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as the second parameter to [`GetProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy0d4103%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the property without checking case:

```
public object GetPropValue(object obj, string propName)
{
     return obj.GetType()
         .GetProperty(propName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase )
         .GetValue(obj, null);
}
```